# MySQL select calculation from subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:
`Jobs`, `invoices`, `invoices_payments`.

Jobs has multiple invoices.

Invoice has multiple payments, therefore `hash` works as id.

```
clients_jobs (hash,name)
invoice (hash, jobs_id, total)
invoice (hash, jobs_id, total)
payment (hash, invoices_id, amount)
payment (hash, invoices_id, amount)
```

I need to generate a MySQL query that would give me a list of jobs with total for all job invoices billed, and total outstanding for all these invoices.
So `SUM(total)` for each invoices related to the job `- SUM(amount)` of each payment for each of those invoices.

I was able to get it down to the following code, which gives me the total for each job and total payments for each job, but not the wanted result.

```
select `clients_jobs`.`name`, 
(
    select SUM(total) as total from `invoices`
    where `clients_jobs_id` = `clients_jobs`.`hash`
) as `invoices_total`, 
(
    select
    (
        select SUM(amount) as total
        from `invoices_payments`
        where `invoices_id` = `invoices`.`hash`
    ) as `payments_total`
    from `invoices`
    where `clients_jobs_id` = `clients_jobs`.`hash`
) as `payments_total`, 
from `clients_jobs` 
where `outstanding` > '0'
```

I tried doing something like

```
SELECT (invoices_total - payments_total) as outstanding
```

but I'm getting an error saying `invoices_total` is unrecognized.

Comment: Make that as subquery then do the calculation. By the way, is this query performance ok?

Comment: "Make that as subquery then do the calculation" - can u elaborate on that or better give me an example. Re performance , i know its probably not the best, but its a very small scale db, im not super good with Mysql so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I mean with what you already have, you might just do something like this:

```
SELECT name, 
       invoices_total, 
       payments_total, 
       (invoices_total - payments_total) as outstanding
FROM

(SELECT `clients_jobs`.`name`, 
(
    SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM `invoices`
    WHERE `clients_jobs_id` = `clients_jobs`.`hash`
) AS `invoices_total`, 
(
    SELECT
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount) AS total
        FROM `invoices_payments`
        WHERE `invoices_id` = `invoices`.`hash`
    ) AS `payments_total`
    FROM `invoices`
    WHERE `clients_jobs_id` = `clients_jobs`.`hash`
) AS `payments_total`, 
FROM `clients_jobs` 
WHERE `outstanding` > '0' ) A;
```

But looking at your query, you might get the same result (hopefully) with this query below:

```
SELECT `clients_jobs`.`name`, 
         SUM(`invoices`.total) AS `invoices_total`, 
         SUM(`invoices`.amount) AS `payments_total`,
         SUM(`invoices`.total)-SUM(`invoices`.amount) AS outstanding
FROM `clients_jobs` 
JOIN `invoices` ON `invoices`.`clients_jobs_id` = `clients_jobs`.`hash`
WHERE `clients_jobs`.`outstanding` > '0' ;
```

Its much shorter and possibly perform better than your original attempt.